# Is Apache Camel typically deployed as a single application?

Tags: apache-camel, messaging

Just getting started with Apache Camel and I am trying to understand how it can be deployed.

Does it make sense to have a single Camel application that is just responsible for routing messages from various queues?

For example, I have several applications writing to an "Orders" queue. Based on some criteria one will end up invoking an RPC in one application, and another will invoke a different RPC.

Do I just deploy a single Camel application that does this routing/invoking?

If I have multiple of these cases, is it common to have a single Camel application handle all such routing?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your local deployment policies.  I have seen deployments where many/numerous queues are managed in a single Camel context with multiple Camel routes.  I have seen pretty much the exact same deployment done as a single Camel route per deployment, with numerous deployments.

'Right sizing' your deployments is kind of up to you.  I have seen enterprise applications that have both tiny little Springboot Camel routes that just move messages between destinations, and also have a single Camel context with numerous Camel routes and a lot of Spring in the mix.

But, yes, if you have six (for example) 'from: to:' routes in a single Camel context, this is a common deployment.

Comment: Got it! Is there a general rule of thumb when it comes to splitting it out? For instance, is 10 ok but is 20 too many? How about 100?

Comment: Some organizations like their micro services very micro.  I was working with a company which liked to only have one route per deployment.  Many Springboot containers.   To be fair, the route was parameterized, so you could deploy the same artifact and just change the parameters.  I have worked with a company that had 157 nearly identical routes in one deployment.  I have worked with applications that were large Spring applications that had three Camel routes thrown in because that made sense.

Comment: There is a company that build a custom product on top of Camel, where they have all their tennants in the same CamelContext, and they have 100.000+ routes. Not that its a good design. But Camel have no limits in the max number of routes.